# view hidden div text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt. 
</div>
```

As you can see, my div has a fixed width and the rest of the content is hidden. I would like to show all the content of my div when I hover the cursor on it (In like a bubble or something). Is this possible with plain HTML, or do I have no other choice but to use JavaScript to do this?

Comment: `div:hover {overflow:visible;}` will show everything. If you want it in a shape then you'll need JS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, if you use `hover`. You have to move your inline style into a class. See here for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/buC6t/

```
.exdiv {
    width:300px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap; 
}
.exdiv:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}

<div class="exdiv">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt. 
</div>
```

Comment: Please also post the most important code you used in the fiddle. The warning is there for a reason. When the fiddles would disappear or jsfiddle goes down, people still get information from this post whereas now, they don't.

Comment: My apologies, Bram... I thought this was a simple solution so didn't want to be overly verbose. It is the most upvoted answer so I suppose I underestimated what people would think of it. My answer has been edited to include the CSS that is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

As a very basic non-CSS non-JavaScript approach you can use tooltip:

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"
        title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt. ">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt. 
</div>
```

Waving mouse over this div will display text in the tooltip. You can also keep initally `title` blank and populate it in JavaScript with something like

```
myDivObj.title = myDivObj.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have bubble, with no js would be duplicated content, but possible:
http://jsfiddle.net/7e4hC/

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;" class="test">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt. 
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt.</span></div>

.test span {
    display: none;
}
.test:hover span {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

or even cleaner:

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;" class="test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis pulvinar dui. Nulla ut metus molestie, dignissim metus et, tincidunt tellus. Fusce porttitor erat ut vestibulum fermentum. Mauris odio nisl, mattis sit amet fermentum sed, consequat non dui. Nullam porta posuere augue eu luctus. Phasellus vulputate, nisl et sagittis consequat, massa nunc pharetra massa, vitae rhoncus elit nisl non mauris. Phasellus sollicitudin venenatis dapibus. Aliquam molestie magna et adipiscing hendrerit. In tempus nulla ut tellus dictum laoreet. Phasellus non nulla tortor. Suspendisse sit amet diam sed velit dignissim tincidunt.</div>

.test:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```